There is a very big problem with the difference in touch sensitivity of PIC
We are making and producing Touch remote control in the environment below.

PIC18F24Q10
MPLAB X IDE v6.20
Touch is created in MCC, and sensitivity is adjusted by sampling and threshold
self capacitance

We made a shield similar to the one below using separate GPIO.


The remote control case is made of ABS and has a thickness of 2.5mm.
The power is supplied by a battery and a separate LDO is used to supply 3.0V to the PIC MCU.

We test the touch sensitivity with rods of different diameters as shown in the figure below.

Problem 1) The touch remote control has been produced 3 times so far. However, the touch sensitivity of specific buttons changes uniformly during each production.

1st production = specific button 9pi
2nd production = specific button 7pi
3rd production = specific button 5pi

Is it normal for the sensitivity of specific buttons to change by about 2pi during each production?
Problem 2) We developed 3 remote controls this time, but one remote control has a large difference in touch sensitivity for each button.
Remote control 1/2 = It varies depending on the production batch, but there is no difference between individual remote controls
Remote control 3 = There is a large difference in sensitivity for each button of the remote control of the same production batch
Remote control 3 ex) Product 1's A button sensitivity 5pi
Product 2's A button sensitivity 9pi
=> The phenomenon that I checked in relation to this is as follows.

After inserting the battery, the touch sensitivity is different after 30 seconds / after 1 minute / after 5 minutes.

It seems that the difference in sensitivity between buttons decreases if you leave it alone for a long time without touching it.

When the threshold of an individual button is modified, the sensitivity of adjacent pattern buttons changes.

In other words, this is the part where interference between buttons is judged to exist, but isn't the difference in each production due to this slight interference?
Due to the difference in the degree of interference...
=> In a situation where we need to stabilize the deviation of touch sensitivity, does the PIC touch library have this much error?
I want to know if there is any way to improve it.

what is the pi in 9pi
